# php redirect not working on WordPress header page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set redirect code for this [page](http://www.roomstonite.com/appstore-fb1/)
I have below code for it

[image: This is the code written in header.php]

but when I open it on Mozilla its not working page just be in the same page again. And its echoing the text perfectly on Mozilla browser.

What is the cause ?
[This](http://www.roomstonite.com/appstore-fb1/) is WordPress website.

Comment: Add `exit` after header redirection code. Also make sure you do not output anything before redirection code.

Comment: Which includes the blank line between the closing and opening PHP tags...

Comment: Also, please don't post screenshots of your code. Post the actual code here.

Comment: Stop playing with your php tag like that (and please do not use image to show your code on SO)

Answer (score 0):

There can't be any output before `header` function. Remove spaces before header outside `<?php` and `?>`, or better, remove second PHP beginning/end tags (put whole script into one `<?php ... ?>`).

```
<?php

if (...) {
   echo 'Andriod';
}

header ('http://www.google.com');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
 1.   <?php wp_redirect( $location, $status ); exit; ?>
 2.   <?php wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 301 ); exit; ?>
```